# Is it acceptable to have circular reference when element in collection needs to know of other elements?

Tags: c#, wpf, oop, mvvm

Lets say I have a class `ApplicationState` which holds the state of an application it has a collection of `Globs`. Each `Glob` must have a unique name therefore it should be somehow related to `ApplicationState` which is holding a list of all `Globs`. My thoughts were that each `Glob` should be capable of its own validation so I introduced `GlobValidator` that checks whether the name is valid by going through the list of `ApplicationState` `Globs`. So now I am wondering whether the fact of `ApplicationState` knowing about `Globs` which know about `GlobValidator` that knows about `AplicationState` will really be painful in the feature and should be changed.

```
public class GlobValidator
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<Glob> _globs;

    public GlobValidator(IEnumerable<Glob> globs )
    {
        _globs = globs;
    }

    public bool IsValidName(string name)
    {
        bool isThereGlobWithSameName = _globs.Any(g => g.Name == name);
        return !isThereGlobWithSameName;
    }
}

public class Glob
{
    private readonly GlobValidator _globValidator;
    private string _name;

    public Glob(string name, GlobValidator globValidator)
    {
        _globValidator = globValidator;
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            if (_globValidator.IsValidName(value))
            {
                _name = value;
            }
        }
    }
}

public class GlobFactory
{
    private readonly GlobValidator _globValidator;

    public GlobFactory(GlobValidator globValidator)
    {
        _globValidator = globValidator;
    }

    public Glob CreateGlob(string name)
    {
        if (!_globValidator.IsValidName(name))
        {
            throw new Exception("Invalid Glob Name");
        }
        return new Glob(name, _globValidator);
    }
}

public class ApplicationState
{
    public ApplicationState()
    {
        Globs = new List<Glob>();
    }

    public List<Glob> Globs { get; set; } 
}
```

The annoyance that I have encountered with thus far is during De-serialization of `ApplicationState` from XML. As Example

```
 ApplicationState
     Globs
     [0] Glob.Name = "John"
     [1] Glob.Name = "Jeff"
```

Now given such state when I de-serialize I cannot give Globs the real `GlobValidator` which has a reference to real `ApplicationState` without clearing the `Globs` from application state, otherwise if there is glob with the same name in xml exception will be thrown by GlobValidator. I do not want to clear all the Globs from ApplicationState preparing for the case that xml is faulty in which case I want the previous `ApplicationState` to be untouched. So now my choice in this approach is to create a temporary reference of `GlobValidator` which has a reference to a temporary `ApplicationState`. The price for this is in the case of successful XML serialization I will need to go through and reset the `GlobValidator` reference on each `Glob` to reference the real validator, this does not sound like a bad tradeoff to me for having ability of Globs validating themselves.

Am I making a mistake trying to have the `Glob` being able to validate themselves? Should I be creating some sort of a wrapper around `Glob` that does the validation using the `ApplicationState`? Or does this approach sound sane?

P.S. I am using WPF so `Glob`s implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and `ApplicationState` has a list of `ObservableCollection` of `Glob's

Comment: I don't understand why both `Glob` and `GlobFactory` need a `GlobValidator`. It look like you can just check for a unique name in `GlobFactory.CreateGlob()`, and not pass a `GlobValidator` to the `Glob` object.

Comment: Lets say I have a an `ObservableCollection<Glob>` that can be the `ItemsSource` of `DataGrid` in which case I want Globs to reject input from the user that is incorrect if they try to change Globs name.

Comment: I would separate the coupling between serialization and validation. Namely, allow the XML to hold invalid lists (duplicate `Glob` names), and check after deserializing. By dropping the requirement of checking `Glob` during construction, I think you would reach a cleaner solution. Also, I would consider passing a `Func<string, bool>` to `Glob`'s constructor, which will avoid an explicit reference to its parent.